# Installing a newer version of PCL on ubuntu

Tags: point-cloud-library

I would like to upgrade my PCL to a newer version to fix a problem I have with QHull related to this [issue](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/issues/1618).
I'm on ubuntu so I installed PCL with `sudo apt install libpcl-dev` but I can only get the version 1.10.1. How can I install a newer version ?
The problem is apparently fixed by this [commit](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/commit/b19c99a5f45950c0e519e631d09adb0c5257596e). It's in the tag 1.12.1.

I know that in theory I can use cmake and build my own PCL but from what I saw with the apt install, there is a huge amount of dependencies + I will also need this particular Qhull version that they mention in the issue and commit... I'm not sure I can make this work without the package manager. Any leads on this problem ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In its simplest form, building and installing PCL goes likes this:

1. Clone the GitHub repo and `cd` inside it
2. Optionally checkout a git tag or stay on the master branch (default)
3. `mkdir build && cd build`
4. Run cmake with `cmake ..`
5. Build and install with `make -j2 && sudo make install`

For more information, see here: https://pcl.readthedocs.io/projects/tutorials/en/master/compiling_pcl_posix.html

When you previously had `libpcl-dev` installed, you can remove that package without (auto-)removing the dependencies, then you should have most if not all dependencies required for building from source already installed.

You didn't say which Ubuntu version you use, but judging from the version of `libpcl-dev`, I assume it is focal (20.04). The Qhull version installed there is fine, it already has a reentrant interface.

Comment: Thank you! Good point that I already have the dependencies with the apt.